# How to check if a string contains any kid of whitespace between characters JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I need to be able to catch whether I have any kind of whitespace between two `,`.

1. `, ,` should return false
2. `,   ,` should also return false
3. and so should `,             ,`

and so on and so on

So far I have this

```
    if(target_url.includes(",,")||target_url.includes(", ,"))
    {
        //code code code
    }
```

So how can I detect whether a string contains any amount of white space between two commas?

Comment: please share a example string

Comment: Regular expressions! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: is `,,` (without space) allowed?

Comment: `,,` is not allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test with a regular expression for whitespace between commas.

```js
var regex = /,\s*,/;

console.log(!regex.test(',   ,')); // false
console.log(!regex.test(',,'));    // false
console.log(!regex.test(',x,'));   //  true
```